# From .ps/.dvi/.pdf, go to the corresponding location of .tex in Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex

I am using Emacs to edit .tex file. It seems that there is a way to view a document (.dvi or .ps), then if we click on the doc, we can go to the corresponding location of .tex file in Emacs, could anyone tell me how to configure Emacs to realize that functionality?

Thank you.

Comment: I have finally used a similar solution from [here](http://inthearmchair.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/latex-inverse-pdf-search-with-emacs/). To conclude, I am now using Okular instead of Evince, and Shift+left click on the .pdf doc to go to the location of .tex file in Emacs. But I have not figured out yet how to do forward search precisely: location from .tex to .pdf quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You want [SyncTeX](http://itexmac.sourceforge.net/SyncTeX.html), and you should also check out [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

It should work out of the box in the cvs-version if you have a well-behaving dbus-system.

If you don't (like me), or if you would rather use release 11.86 for now you could use the following scripts. They are modified versions of other peoples' effort (see (c) and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1716268).

You just ctrl + left click in your pdf file (the file must of course have synctex info).

Evince-backward-search (note the shebang):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Copyright (C) 2010 Jose Aliste <jose.aliste@gmail.com>
#               2011 Benjamin Kellermann <Benjamin.Kellermann@tu-dresden.de>
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
# the terms of the GNU General Public Licence as published by the Free Software
# Foundation; either version 2 of the Licence, or (at your option) any later
# version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public Licence for more
# details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public Licence along with
# this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin
# Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA

import dbus, subprocess, time, re

RUNNING, CLOSED = range(2)

EV_DAEMON_PATH = "/org/gnome/evince/Daemon"
EV_DAEMON_NAME = "org.gnome.evince.Daemon"
EV_DAEMON_IFACE = "org.gnome.evince.Daemon"

EVINCE_PATH = "/org/gnome/evince/Evince"
EVINCE_IFACE = "org.gnome.evince.Application"

EV_WINDOW_IFACE = "org.gnome.evince.Window"



class EvinceWindowProxy:
    """A DBUS proxy for an Evince Window."""
    daemon = None
    bus = None

    def __init__(self, uri, editor, spawn = False, logger = None):
        self._log = logger
        self.uri = uri
        self.editor = editor
        self.status = CLOSED
        self.source_handler = None
        self.dbus_name = ''
        self._handler = None
        try:
            if EvinceWindowProxy.bus is None:
                EvinceWindowProxy.bus = dbus.SessionBus()

            if EvinceWindowProxy.daemon is None:
                EvinceWindowProxy.daemon = EvinceWindowProxy.bus.get_object(EV_DAEMON_NAME,
                                                EV_DAEMON_PATH,
                                                follow_name_owner_changes=True)
            EvinceWindowProxy.bus.add_signal_receiver(self._on_doc_loaded, signal_name="DocumentLoaded", 
                                                      dbus_interface = EV_WINDOW_IFACE, 
                                                      sender_keyword='sender')
            self._get_dbus_name(False)

        except dbus.DBusException:
            if self._log:
                self._log.debug("Could not connect to the Evince Daemon")

    def _on_doc_loaded(self, uri, **keyargs):
        if uri == self.uri and self._handler is None:
            self.handle_find_document_reply(keyargs['sender'])

    def _get_dbus_name(self, spawn):
        EvinceWindowProxy.daemon.FindDocument(self.uri,spawn,
                     reply_handler=self.handle_find_document_reply,
                     error_handler=self.handle_find_document_error,
                     dbus_interface = EV_DAEMON_IFACE)

    def handle_find_document_error(self, error):
        if self._log:
            self._log.debug("FindDocument DBus call has failed")

    def handle_find_document_reply(self, evince_name):
        if self._handler is not None:
            handler = self._handler
        else:
            handler = self.handle_get_window_list_reply
        if evince_name != '':
            self.dbus_name = evince_name
            self.status = RUNNING
            self.evince = EvinceWindowProxy.bus.get_object(self.dbus_name, EVINCE_PATH)
            self.evince.GetWindowList(dbus_interface = EVINCE_IFACE,
                          reply_handler = handler,
                          error_handler = self.handle_get_window_list_error)

    def handle_get_window_list_error (self, e):
        if self._log:
            self._log.debug("GetWindowList DBus call has failed")

    def handle_get_window_list_reply (self, window_list):
        if len(window_list) > 0:
            window_obj = EvinceWindowProxy.bus.get_object(self.dbus_name, window_list[0])
            self.window = dbus.Interface(window_obj,EV_WINDOW_IFACE)
            self.window.connect_to_signal("SyncSource", self.on_sync_source)
        else:
            #That should never happen. 
            if self._log:
                self._log.debug("GetWindowList returned empty list")

    def on_sync_source(self, input_file, source_link):
        print input_file + ":" + str(source_link[0])
        cmd = re.sub("%f",input_file,self.editor)
        cmd = re.sub("%l",str(source_link[0]), cmd)
        print cmd
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
        if self.source_handler is not None:
            self.source_handler(input_file, source_link)


## This file offers backward search in any editor.
##  evince_dbus  pdf_file  line_source input_file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import dbus.mainloop.glib, gobject, glib, sys, os

    def print_usage():
        print """Usage: 
  evince_backward_search pdf_file "editorcmd %f %l"'
    %f ... TeX-file to load
    %l ... line to jump to
E.g.:
  evince_backward_search somepdf.pdf "gvim --servername somepdf --remote '+%l<Enter>' %f"
  evince_backward_search somepdf.pdf "emacsclient -a emacs --no-wait +%l %f"
  evince_backward_search somepdf.pdf "scite %f '-goto:%l'"
  evince_backward_search somepdf.pdf "lyxclient -g %f %l"
  evince_backward_search somepdf.pdf "kate --use --line %l"
  evince_backward_search somepdf.pdf "kile --line %l" """
        sys.exit(1)

    if len(sys.argv)!=3:
        print_usage()

    pdf_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])

    if not os.path.isfile(pdf_file):
        print_usage()

    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    a = EvinceWindowProxy('file://' + pdf_file, sys.argv[2] ,True)


    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run() 
# ex:ts=4:et:
```

Evince Forward Search:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Copyright (C) 2010 Jose Aliste <jose.aliste@gmail.com>
#               2011 Benjamin Kellermann <Benjamin.Kellermann@tu-dresden.de>
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
# the terms of the GNU General Public Licence as published by the Free Software
# Foundation; either version 2 of the Licence, or (at your option) any later
# version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
# FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public Licence for more 
# details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public Licence along with
# this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin
# Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA

# This file offers forward search for evince.

import dbus, subprocess, time, sys, os

def print_usage():
    print 'Usage: evince_forward_search pdf_file line_number tex_file\n   or: evince_forward_search pdf_file tex_file' 
    sys.exit(1)

if len(sys.argv)< 3 or len(sys.argv)>4: 
    print_usage()

if len(sys.argv)==4 :
    try:
        line_number = int(sys.argv[2])
    except ValueError:
        print_usage()

    pdf_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
    tex_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[3])
if len(sys.argv)==3 :
    line_number  = 0
    pdf_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
    tex_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])
try:
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    daemon = bus.get_object('org.gnome.evince.Daemon', '/org/gnome/evince/Daemon')
    dbus_name = daemon.FindDocument('file://' + pdf_file, True, dbus_interface = "org.gnome.evince.Daemon")
    window = bus.get_object(dbus_name, '/org/gnome/evince/Window/0')
except dbus.DBusException:
    print_exc()     

if len(sys.argv)==4 :
    window.SyncView(tex_file, (line_number,1), dbus_interface="org.gnome.evince.Window")

if len(sys.argv)==3 :
    subprocess.Popen(["evince",pdf_file])
```

Evince (I store it in my ~/bin, but a more suitable name might be better):

```
#!/bin/sh
EDITORCMD="emacsclient -a '' --no-wait +%l %f"
PDFFILE="$1"

~/bin/evince_forward_search "$@"

if [ -f "$PDFFILE" ];then
    if [ -f `basename "$PDFFILE" .pdf`.synctex.gz ];then
        ~/build/evince_backward_search "$PDFFILE" "$EDITORCMD"&
        BACKWARD_SEARCH_PID=$!
        echo $BACKWARD_SEARCH_PID
    fi
fi

if [ "$BACKWARD_SEARCH_PID" ];then
    echo "Killing $BACKWARD_SEARCH_PID"
    kill $BACKWARD_SEARCH_PID
fi
```

Here is the relevant snip from my Emacs-config (format in Org):

```
*** Make Evince synctex friendly 
I want to use [[http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t%3D1716268][these scripts]] to make AUCTeX more synctex friendly.
The evince sh script is found [[file:~/bin/evince][here]].

The process is as follows:
 1. AUCTeX should call the ~/bin/evince rather than /usr/bin/evince
 2. local evince in turn call [[~/bin/evince_backward_search][evince_backward_search]] (with two
    arguments, pdf and editor) and  [[file:~/bin/evince_forward%20script][evince_forward script]] with two to
    three arguments
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
;;      ("Evince" ("evince" (mode-io-correlate " -p %(outpage)") " %o"))
(add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
(quote ("Evince2" ("~/bin/evince %o " (mode-io-correlate "%n ") "%t"))))
;;(setq TeX-view-program-selection (quote (((output-dvi style-pstricks) "dvips and gv") (output-dvi "xdvi") (output-pdf "Evince2") (output-html "xdg-open"))))
(add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection
         (quote (output-pdf "Evince2")))
#+end_src
```

This whole thing probably sucks -- I am no programmer! I've just put the above together for a workable solution.

Note: You will not get the red box, highlighting the current tex-file line in the cvs-version of AUCTeX.